# size returning different sizes for different format

Tags: c, size

[image: size returns unmatched values for different formats]

Here is the simple code which is compiled for getting scanfProb ELF and when I ran size command on the same for different formats above is the result i got. I'm not sure why the total sizes returned for different formats are mismatching

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{

int a;

while (1){
    printf("enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("entered number is %d\n", a);
}




return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since the difference between 2004 and 1952 is 52, and the size of the `.comment` section is 52, there's a chance that `size` doesn't count the comment section.  (Of course, `.eh_frame_hdr` is also 52; and there may be other sets of sections that add up to 52 bytes, but the `.comment` section is much more likely to be the issue.)

Comment: @jonathan I too initially suspected the .comment section, but if you see I don't have any comments in my code so do you think the comments are from studio.h file? Also FYI, the man page of size doesn't list this exhaustive list for size command in SysV mode and their totals matched in the example provided (which obviously looks like documentation for a older version of size) as SysV listed the three same outputs as Berkeley format.

Comment: The `.comments` section doesn't store `/* C style */` comments, or `// C++ style <EOL>` comments.  I've no other information to offer, AFAIK, unless something or someone manages to jog a long-forgotten memory with some suitable remark.